# How to debug a Segmentation Fault in this code?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

> Question: Intersecting Merge Sort
>
> ```
>        Input--abc//first string
>              def//second string
>               Output-- adbecf 
>               Input 2-- abc
>                       defgh 
>               Output    adbecfgh**
> ```

I am getting segmentation fault in my code and I don't know why. I don't think my code points to any invalid pointer, how can I remove this code?

Here is my solution code in C

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
char *mergeTwo(char *a,char *b)
{   char *c;int k=0,i=0;
   while(1)
   {
       if(a[i]!='\0' && b[i]!='\0')
       {
           if(a[i]>=b[i])
           {
               c[k++]=b[i];
               c[k++]=a[i];
           }
           else
           { c[k++]=a[i];
               c[k++]=b[i];

           }
       }
       else if(a[i]!='\0' && b[i]=='\0')
       {
           c[k++]=a[i];
       }
       else if(a[i]=='\0' && b[i]!='\0')
       {
           c[k++]=b[i];
       }
       else if(a[i]=='\0' && b[i]=='\0')
       {
           c[k]='\0';
           break;
       }i++;
   }
return c;    
}

int main() {
    char str1[100],str2[100],*str3;
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    str3= mergeTwo(str1,str2);
    puts(str3);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Where do you allocate the memory that c points to??

Comment: first, you should initialize (or at least NULL-terminate) `str1` and `str2` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issue:

As noted by dresxherim:  *c has no memory allocated. and is free only when the process exists.

Current logic assume both strings are the same length.  When one is longer you will also get a segmentation fault.

```
char *mergeTwo(char *a,char *b)
{  char *c;int k=0,i=0, j=0;

   c = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1); // include null for termination.

   while(1)
   {

//  Code reworked for if string A and B are different lengths.

   if(a[i]!='\0' && b[j]!='\0')
   {
       if(a[i]>=b[j])
       {
           c[k++]=b[j++];
           c[k++]=a[i++];
       }
       else
       {   c[k++]=a[i++];
           c[k++]=b[j++];

       }
   }
   else if(a[i]!='\0')
   {
       c[k++]=a[i++];
   }
   else if(b[j]!='\0')
   {
       c[k++]=b[j++];
   }
   else { // if(a[i]=='\0' && b[j]=='\0')

       c[k]='\0';
       break;
   }
} // end while

return c;    
}



int main() {
    char str1[100],str2[100],*str3;
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    str3= mergeTwo(str1,str2);
    puts(str3);
    free(str3);  // free memory allocated.
    return 0;
}
```

Saved as test.c, Compile and tesed on OS X:

```
$ cc test.c 
$ ./a.out  
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe. 
abc 
def 
adbecf
```